# Why can I not install snakemake on my SLURM computer even though I can find it in the bioconda channel?

Tags: software-installation, snakemake, bioconda, anaconda

I searched for the package 'snakemake' on my SLURM cluster using:

`conda search --channel bioconda snakemake`

and I get many versions, up to 5.4.2.

I then try to install it using:

`conda install --channel bioconda --yes snakemake=5.4.2`

but it fails with the following message:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - snakemake

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
```

Why?

Why is the bioconda channel not included in the current channels? I thought that was what the `--channel bioconda` did in my install command.

Note that `conda install --channel bioconda --yes samtools=1.9` worked fine and installed samtools successfully.

Comment: I've heard some folks warn that conda is sensitive to the order in which channels are set/configured. I'm not exactly sure what the details are, but maybe that gives you somewhere to start troubleshooting?

Answer (score 2):

I created a file .condarc in my home directory with the following content:

```
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
```

and it works now. I don't understand why this is necessary though. I thought the channels in the .condarc file would be used if I did not specify them in my command.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the version of `conda` you're using, it works in 4.6.4. Note, however, that you needed to add `-c conda-forge` to your original command anyway, since many of the snakemake dependencies come from there.

Comment: good point about the dependencies. I didn't know about that. I just always give the channel of the package I want to install but it sounds like I also need to give the channel of dependencies. So I'll keep using `-c conda-forge -c bioconda -c r` in all my `conda install` commands.